# Using REGEX to Extract the text from the Data

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have created below formula which works for some of the data not for the entire. I have been trying to extract those values which has `?` at end where two cells are `<>""`.

Any help will be appreciatd.

```
=IF(OR(B2<>"",C2<>""),IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"^\*\*\*\ HEDAL - (.* )? ")),0)
```

[image]

[Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11nMayGP6Dj1Lue_OJISQYo70IqwCtYxAq5zV-bEs3-k/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Please add the data you have and expected output to the question.

Comment: Sure I have added

Comment: Can't see it here.

Comment: I have updated the picture with required result for the data i have attached the sheet @Wiktor Stribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
=IF(OR(B2<>"",C2<>""),IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"^\*\*\*\ HEDAL - (.*?\?) +- ")),"")
```

See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/ih5h2p/1). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `***\ HEDAL -`  - `*** HEDAL -`  text
- `(.*?\?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, then a `?` char (**note** you might need to change `.*?` to `[^-]*` to avoid matching the boundary `-` char)
- `+-`  - zero or more spaces, `-` and a space.

Demo screenshot:

[image]